# Pandas: Convert a JSON column with multiple rows into multiple dataframe rows

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: `countries` and `year`. The `countries` column is JSON in the form of:

```
[{'continent': 'europe',
  'country': 'Yugoslavia',
  'income': None,
  'life_exp': None,
  'population': 4687422},
 {'continent': 'asia',
  'country': 'United Korea (former)',
  'income': None,
  'life_exp': None,
  'population': 13740000},
 {'continent': 'asia',
  'country': 'Tokelau',
  'income': None,
  'life_exp': None,
  'population': 1009},
  ...
```

How can I convert this dataframe into something like:

```
continent | country | income | life_exp | population | year
----------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------
europe    | Yugos   | None   | None     | 4600000    | 1800
asia      | Korea   | None   ||None     | 13000000   | 1800
asia      | Tokelau | None   | None     | 1009       | 1800
```

That's to split the JSON column into several rows with its corresponding columns, AND adding the year that corresponds to that row?

I used `json_normalize()` on the column and it gives me the columns I need, but I don't know how I may add the year at the end

EDIT:
This is my original dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
print(df-head())

                                           countries  year
0  [{'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavi...  1800
1  [{'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Svalbard'...  1801
2  [{'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Svalbard'...  1802
3  [{'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'Wallis et F...  1803
4  [{'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'Wallis et F...  1804
```

The countries column is a JSON with multiple rows of data, the year applies to all that data, so how can I convert it to a dataframe with all the rows and the corresponding year in each row?

I know that if I do `pd.DataFrame(df.countries[0])` will produce the dataframe with all the countries for the first row, but I don't know how to add the year to a new column. I think a loop would do, but I also guess there must be a much more efficient way

**EDIT**: this loop would produce the result I need, but I think it is highly inefficient:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['continent', 'country', 'income', 'life_exp', 'population', 'year'])

for i in range(len(old_df)):
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df.countries[i])
    temp_df['year'] = old_df.year[i]
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)
```

There must be a better way, right?

Comment: How about you loop through the json file and format it in such a way to get your result instead of looping through the dataframe? This is better?

Comment: I don't know... I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this with [`explode`](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-explode.php#:%7E:text=The%20explode()%20function%20is,row%2C%20replicating%20the%20index%20values.&text=Exploded%20lists%20to%20rows%20of,be%20duplicated%20for%20these%20rows.):

```
df=df.explode('countries')
#we add to each dictionary the respective value of year with key 'year'
df['countries']=[{**dc,**{'year':y}} for dc,y in zip(df['countries'],df['year'])]
pd.DataFrame(df['countries'].tolist())
```

---

**Example**:

```
j = [{'continent': 'europe',
 'country': 'Yugoslavia',
 'income': None,
  'life_exp': None,
'population': 4687422},
{'continent': 'asia',
'country': 'United Korea (former)',
'income': None,
'life_exp': None,
'population': 13740000}]
df=pd.DataFrame({'countries':[j,j],'year':[1800,1900]})
print(df)

df=df.explode('countries')
print(df)

#Here we add the key 'year' with the respective year row value to each dictionary
df['countries']=[{**dc,**{'year':y}} for dc,y in zip(df['countries'],df['year'])]
print(df['countries'])

finaldf=pd.DataFrame(df['countries'].tolist())
print(finaldf)
```

Output:

```
original df:
                                           countries  year
0  [{'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavi...  1800
1  [{'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavi...  1900


    

df(after explode): 
                                                                                            
                                           countries  year
0  {'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavia...  1800
0  {'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'United Korea...  1800
1  {'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavia...  1900
1  {'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'United Korea...  1900


df.countries(with year added):
0    {'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavia', 'income': None, 'life_exp': None, 'population': 4687422, 'year': 1800}
0    {'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'United Korea (former)', 'income': None, 'life_exp': None, 'population': 13740000, 'year': 1800}
1    {'continent': 'europe', 'country': 'Yugoslavia', 'income': None, 'life_exp': None, 'population': 4687422, 'year': 1900}
1    {'continent': 'asia', 'country': 'United Korea (former)', 'income': None, 'life_exp': None, 'population': 13740000, 'year': 1900}
Name: countries, dtype: object

finaldf
  continent                country income life_exp  population  year
0    europe             Yugoslavia   None     None     4687422  1800
1      asia  United Korea (former)   None     None    13740000  1800
2    europe             Yugoslavia   None     None     4687422  1900
3      asia  United Korea (former)   None     None    13740000  1900
```

Comment: I don't understand what the code says, but yeah, it works and it's hyper-fast

Comment: What are the asterisk for? What to they mean?

Comment: I'm adding the details, sorry @luisfer

Comment: No, thanks a lot. I'm amazed on how many things exists in the language! Thanks a lot for your time and patience!

Comment: It will take a while until I fully understand this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for accepting :), I'll appreciate your upvote too. And, basically the ** is to iterate by each (key, value) pair of the dictionaries, so in that line I'm basically adding each year value to the dictionary @luisfer

Answer (score 1):

should add `ignore_index=True` argument in `explode` function to make sure the following `join` is not messed up.

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('countries', ignore_index=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('countries')))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.join` with `pd.json_normalize`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('countries')))
print(df)
```

Edit as per comment

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('countries')
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('countries')))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   year continent                country income life_exp  population
0  1800    europe             Yugoslavia   None     None     4687422
1  1801      asia  United Korea (former)   None     None    13740000
2  1802      asia                Tokelau   None     None        1009
```

Comment: Will this work if the one row has multiple jsons as it's a json array?

Comment: @bigbounty. Sorry i dnt understand

Comment: When you see the jsons in the dataframe in the question one row in countries is an array of jsons i.e one row can have multiple jsons. So, when we apply the above solution will it work?

Comment: Oh i see missed to see you had a `list` of `dict` in each row.. use `df.explode` Ex: `df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('countries')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply method to vectorize and then get the corresponding tag from the `country` column. Since you have a key named country, use it outside the `for` loop. It would look something like this

```
attribute = ['continent', 'income', 'life_exp', 'population']

for attr in attribute:
    df[attr] = df.country.apply(lambda x: x[attr])
df['country'] = df.country.apply(lambda x: x['country'])
```

The benefit here is that you are only looping with the number of attributes rather than through each item.