# how do I flatten json data (from a list) into separate columns in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe

```
    asin        salesMetricsByAsin                                                      
0   B001U81442  [{'reportingDate': '2021-01-20', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 5.25, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 1, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 1, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': 84, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 3, 'conversionRate': 0.3333}}, {'reportingDate': '2021-01-21', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}]    AMAZON_RETAIL
1   B003SVYRNE  [{'reportingDate': '2021-06-28', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 1, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}, {'reportingDate': '2021-06-29', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}]    AMAZON_RE
```

How do I flatten the list in the `salesMetricsByAsin` column into separate columns?  I have tried several methods including from_dict() and json_normalize() but I am running into issues since the json data is in a list.

Comment: What is a form of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar in structure to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63166896/5494437). My answer is adjusted from one of the answers there.

You need to break the problem down into the following steps:

1. convert the rows in 'salesMetricsByAsin' containing a list of jsons to seperate rows
2. flatten the json into seperate columns

For step 1, you can use df.[explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)('column_name'). For step 2, you can indeed use [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'asin' : ['B001U81442', 'B003SVYRNE'], 
    'salesMetricsByAsin' : [
        [{'reportingDate': '2021-01-20', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 5.25, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 1, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 1, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': 84, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 3, 'conversionRate': 0.3333}}, 
         {'reportingDate': '2021-01-21', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}],
        [{'reportingDate': '2021-06-28', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 1, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}, 
         {'reportingDate': '2021-06-29', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}],
    ],
    '3rd_col' : ['AMAZON_RETAIL', 'AMAZON_RE']
}    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_2 = df.explode('salesMetricsByAsin').reset_index()
df_2.join(pd.json_normalize(df_2.pop('salesMetricsByAsin')))
```

Output:

```
index   asin    3rd_col reportingDate   salesMetricsByDate.shippedRevenue.amount    salesMetricsByDate.shippedRevenue.currencyCode  salesMetricsByDate.shippedCOGS.amount   salesMetricsByDate.shippedCOGS.currencyCode salesMetricsByDate.shippedUnits salesMetricsByDate.customerReturns  ... salesMetricsByDate.orderedRevenue.amount    salesMetricsByDate.orderedRevenue.currencyCode  salesMetricsByDate.orderedUnits salesMetricsByDate.preOrderedUnits  salesMetricsByDate.shippedSubcategorySalesRank  salesMetricsByDate.orderedSubcategorySalesRank  salesMetricsByDate.replenishableOutOfStock  salesMetricsByDate.lostBuyBox   salesMetricsByDate.glanceViews  salesMetricsByDate.conversionRate
0   0   B001U81442  AMAZON_RETAIL   2021-01-20  9.99    USD 5.25    USD 1   0   ... 9.99    USD 1   0   84.0    83.0    0.0 0.0 3   0.3333
1   0   B001U81442  AMAZON_RETAIL   2021-01-21  0.00    USD 0.00    USD 0   0   ... 0.00    USD 0   0   NaN 83.0    0.0 0.0 0   0.0000
2   1   B003SVYRNE  AMAZON_RE   2021-06-28  0.00    USD 0.00    USD 0   1   ... 0.00    USD 0   0   NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 0   0.0000
3   1   B003SVYRNE  AMAZON_RE   2021-06-29  0.00    USD 0.00    USD 0   0   ... 0.00    USD 0   0   NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 0   0.0000
```

Comment: Niels, thank you!!!!!  I had attempted something similar, but I was missing the pop() step.  Brilliant solution!. I just tried it and it worked perfectly.  I am so thankful!

Comment: that's great to hear! took me a bit of fiddling around. If it worked for you please mark the answer as the accepted answer :)